# CopyFile/CopyFileEx not working in Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 x64

Tags: c++, windows-server-2008-r2

I have installed the OS in VirtualBox 4.3.8

I have compiled the Code that calls the CopyFile/CopyFileEx function in VC6, and VS2012 (for v10 and v11), but it refuses to work.

I am running the app in console mode, as Administrator.
It gives error 2: `The system cannot find the file specified.`

However, this code works fine for both functions on XP, Server 2003, and Windows 7.

What is the problem?  Is it permissions?  How can I find out what the problem is?

Comment: The problem is that the file that you named does not exist.

Comment: Please add some code, and some info about source and target (is one of them a network location)? Are you able to copy the according file from the console manually?

Comment: @sb9 +1, `copy C:\Temp\a.txt C:\Temp\b.txt` isn't working in the console.

Comment: What error message? Does `c:\temp\a.txt` exist, if so is it readable? What about `c:\temp\b.txt`, does it exist and if s, is it writable? If copying from the console is not working it of course won't work from your app as well... (+1 went to David)

Comment: +1 to you both, thanks, the problem was my own, the source file did not exist, and the reason I didn't know, was because in 2008 they added the "feature" 'Hide extensions for known file types.', which I forgot to uncheck, so I coudln't see that the filename was wrong.  Thanks sb9 for providing me with helpful debug steps.

Comment: The very sad part, is that I had tested to see if this file existed, by pasting "C:\Temp\a.txt" into Windows Explorer address bar and pressing return, and it opened it in notepad.  You can reproduce this right now. ('Hide extensions for known file types.' must be checked.) This is very disturbing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [`ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382.aspx#ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND). It's hard to look beyond the obvious explanation that the file name that you are providing when calling `CopyFile` refers to a file that does not exist.

Comment: It is hard.  Please see my comments above for the logic flaw that created this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Altough you don't give much info about the code, I recommend to download and run [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) in background (you can filter your process).

You will see more detailed info such us if the folder really exists, etc.